# Not getting data on kibana UI with elasticSearch/Logstash on Windows using IIS

Tags: iis, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm installing Logstash with elasticSearch on Windows with Kibana UI. I'm using IIS for this. I'm following [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140802054039/http://community.ulyaoth.net:80/threads/how-to-install-logstash-on-a-windows-server-with-kibana-in-iis.17/) to configure all these on my laptop.

I did exactly the same what was shown in the turorial, I have configured ElasticSearch and logstash on auto-start and I'm able to get the Main page of kibana when I go to the url `loghost.kibanaproject.net` (actually its `127.0.0.1:80`) but, I'm unable to get sample log-data from the a sample Json file.

The file is placed in the root directory in the kibana folder (`C:/kibanaproject/kibana`) but its not showing the data from the file while according to the tutorial it should display the data on UI.

Also when I go to the IIS(Internet Information Service):

> Manager -> User -> Sites -> loghost.kibanaproject.net -> Basic Settings -> Test Setting

there is a warning icon on `Authorization` showing:

```
Cannot verify access to path(C:/kibanaproject/kibana)".
```

Don't know how to resolve it or I'm missing something ? Any help will be highly appreciated.